# app doesn't appear under other simulator iOS versions

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

My deployment target is 3.2, but when i change the simulator version to 3.2 through the "Hardware" menu, it doesn't show up as installed.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Xcode to install under the iOS 3.2 simulator, because when you build for the simulator, Xcode only builds for one version at a time (you may currently be building for 4.2 for example).

After installing from Xcode, though, your simulator for that given version will keep the app; changing build versions later won't cause your app to be uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install an app in each Simulator device & OS combination you want to use.  Each Simulated device & iOS combination stores apps in a different Simulator Application Support sub-directory.

It's possible that different iOS versions may require this because they may occasionally use slightly different app directory or app meta-data.

Comment: alright, but HOW do i install them? the only way i know is the automatic installation that happens when you build & run. When i build & run from xcode it always goes to iphone ios 4.2 simulation....

Comment: There's a menu in Xcode to select which Simulator (device & OS version) to use for build and run.  If you can find the Simulator support directories, you might also be able to copy the super-directory of an app bundle from one OS to another, manually.